# Symfony Form: EntityType, Choice Label and related entity

Tags: php, symfony-forms, symfony

I´ve got an entity `News` and a related entity `NewsArticle` which holds the translations of some `News` attributes (`Headline`, `Subheader`, `Bodytext`). The form to add/edit the `News` records needs a field to select related `News`, so I defined a `EntityType` field for this purpose. The label of each selectable `News` record should display the headline of the `NewsArticle` record with a specific field value (the default language). But how can I realise this?

Even my first attempt by using the `__toString()` method failed with this error message:

> Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection could not be converted to string

The `News` entity:

```
<?php

// src/Acme/Bundle/Entity/News.php
namespace Acme\Bundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="news")
 */
class News {
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="NewsArticle", mappedBy="news", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    protected $newsArticle;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=150, unique=false, nullable=false)
     */
    private $ident;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $validFrom;    

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $validTo;        

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="NewsImage", mappedBy="news")
     */
    protected $image; 

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Media", mappedBy="news")
     */
    private $media;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="News", inversedBy="relatedTo")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="news_to_news",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="from_news_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="to_news_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     * )
     */
    private $relatedFrom;     

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="News", mappedBy="relatedFrom")
     */
    private $relatedTo;           

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Artist")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="artist_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $artist;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     */
    private $public;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", nullable=true)
     */
    private $deleted;    

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->newsArticle = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        $this->image = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        $this->media = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        $this->relatedFrom = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        $this->relatedTo = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set ident
     *
     * @param string $ident
     *
     * @return News
     */
    public function setIdent($ident)
    {
        $this->ident = $ident;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get ident
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getIdent()
    {
        return $this->ident;
    }

    /**
     * Set validFrom
     *
     * @param \DateTime $validFrom
     *
     * @return News
     */
    public function setValidFrom($validFrom)
    {
        $this->validFrom = $validFrom;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get validFrom
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getValidFrom()
    {
        return $this->validFrom;
    }

    /**
     * Set validTo
     *
     * @param \DateTime $validTo
     *
     * @return News
     */
    public function setValidTo($validTo)
    {
        $this->validTo = $validTo;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get validTo
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getValidTo()
    {
        return $this->validTo;
    }

    /**
     * Set public
     *
     * @param boolean $public
     *
     * @return News
     */
    public function setPublic($public)
    {
        $this->public = $public;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get public
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function getPublic()
    {
        return $this->public;
    }

    /**
     * Set deleted
     *
     * @param boolean $deleted
     *
     * @return News
     */
    public function setDeleted($deleted)
    {
        $this->deleted = $deleted;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get deleted
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function getDeleted()
    {
        return $this->deleted;
    }

    /**
     * Add newsArticle
     *
     * @param \Acme\Bundle\Entity\NewsArticle $newsArticle
     *
     * @return News
     */
    public function addNewsArticle(\Acme\Bundle\Entity\NewsArticle $newsArticle)
    {
        $this->newsArticle[] = $newsArticle;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove newsArticle
     *
     * @param \Acme\Bundle\Entity\NewsArticle $newsArticle
     */
    public function removeNewsArticle(\Acme\Bundle\Entity\NewsArticle $newsArticle)
    {
        $this->newsArticle->removeElement($newsArticle);
    }

    /**
     * Get newsArticle
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getNewsArticle()
    {
        return $this->newsArticle;
    }

    /**
     * Add image
     *
     * @param \Acme\Bundle\Entity\NewsImage $image
     *
     * @return News
     */
    public function addImage(\Acme\Bundle\Entity\NewsImage $image)
    {
        $this->image[] = $image;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove image
     *
     * @param \Acme\Bundle\Entity\NewsImage $image
     */
    public function removeImage(\Acme\Bundle\Entity\NewsImage $image)
    {
        $this->image->removeElement($image);
    }

    /**
     * Get image
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getImage()
    {
        return $this->image;
    }

    /**
     * Add medium
     *
     * @param \Acme\Bundle\Entity\Media $medium
     *
     * @return News
     */
    public function addMedia(\Acme\Bundle\Entity\Media $medium)
    {
        $this->media[] = $medium;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove medium
     *
     * @param \Acme\Bundle\Entity\Media $medium
     */
    public function removeMedia(\Acme\Bundle\Entity\Media $medium)
    {
        $this->media->removeElement($medium);
    }

    /**
     * Get media
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getMedia()
    {
        return $this->media;
    }

    /**
     * Add relatedFrom
     *
     * @param \Acme\Bundle\Entity\News $relatedFrom
     *
     * @return News
     */
    public function addRelatedFrom(\Acme\Bundle\Entity\News $relatedFrom)
    {
        $this->relatedFrom[] = $relatedFrom;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove relatedFrom
     *
     * @param \Acme\Bundle\Entity\News $relatedFrom
     */
    public function removeRelatedFrom(\Acme\Bundle\Entity\News $relatedFrom)
    {
        $this->relatedFrom->removeElement($relatedFrom);
    }

    /**
     * Get relatedFrom
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getRelatedFrom()
    {
        return $this->relatedFrom;
    }

    /**
     * Add relatedTo
     *
     * @param \Acme\Bundle\Entity\News $relatedTo
     *
     * @return News
     */
    public function addRelatedTo(\Acme\Bundle\Entity\News $relatedTo)
    {
        $this->relatedTo[] = $relatedTo;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove relatedTo
     *
     * @param \Acme\Bundle\Entity\News $relatedTo
     */
    public function removeRelatedTo(\Acme\Bundle\Entity\News $relatedTo)
    {
        $this->relatedTo->removeElement($relatedTo);
    }

    /**
     * Get relatedTo
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getRelatedTo()
    {
        return $this->relatedTo;
    }

    /**
     * Set artist
     *
     * @param \Acme\Bundle\Entity\Artist $artist
     *
     * @return News
     */
    public function setArtist(\Acme\Bundle\Entity\Artist $artist = null)
    {
        $this->artist = $artist;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get artist
     *
     * @return \Acme\Bundle\Entity\Artist
     */
    public function getArtist()
    {
        return $this->artist;
    }
}
```

The `NewsArticle` entity:

```
<?php

// src/Acme/Bundle/Entity/NewsArticle.php

namespace Acme\Bundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="news_article")
 */
class NewsArticle {

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="News", inversedBy="newsArticle")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="news_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $news;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=150, unique=false, nullable=false)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $headline;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=150, nullable=true)
     */
    private $subheadline;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=65536, nullable=false)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $bodytext;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Language")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="language_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $languageId;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set headline
     *
     * @param string $headline
     *
     * @return NewsArticle
     */
    public function setHeadline($headline)
    {
        $this->headline = $headline;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get headline
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getHeadline()
    {
        return $this->headline;
    }

    /**
     * Set subheadline
     *
     * @param string $subheadline
     *
     * @return NewsArticle
     */
    public function setSubheadline($subheadline)
    {
        $this->subheadline = $subheadline;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get subheadline
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSubheadline()
    {
        return $this->subheadline;
    }

    /**
     * Set bodytext
     *
     * @param string $bodytext
     *
     * @return NewsArticle
     */
    public function setBodytext($bodytext)
    {
        $this->bodytext = $bodytext;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get bodytext
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getBodytext()
    {
        return $this->bodytext;
    }

    /**
     * Set news
     *
     * @param \Acme\Bundle\Entity\News $news
     *
     * @return NewsArticle
     */
    public function setNews(\Acme\Bundle\Entity\News $news = null)
    {
        $this->news = $news;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get news
     *
     * @return \Acme\Bundle\Entity\News
     */
    public function getNews()
    {
        return $this->news;
    }

    /**
     * Set languageId
     *
     * @param \Acme\Bundle\Entity\Language $languageId
     *
     * @return NewsArticle
     */
    public function setLanguageId(\Acme\Bundle\Entity\Language $languageId = null)
    {
        $this->languageId = $languageId;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get languageId
     *
     * @return \Acme\Bundle\Entity\Language
     */
    public function getLanguageId()
    {
        return $this->languageId;
    }

    public function __toString() {
        return $this->getHeadline();
    }
}
```

The NewsType Class (except):

```
class NewsType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder
// [...]
            ->add('relatedTo', EntityType::class, array(
                'class' => 'Bundle:News',
                'choice_label' => function($news) {
                    return $news->getNewsArticle();
                },
                'multiple' => true, 
                'expanded' => false,
                'required' => false
            ))
// [...]
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Acme\Bundle\Entity\News',
        ));
    }
}
```

Any hints how to accomplish the goal? I would be grateful for any help!

---

### EDIT #1:

Thanks to Terenoth I was able to pass the variable containing the default `Language` object to the `NewsType` class and followed his code example to filter the `News` entities having the default language.
Solely returning the `headline` attribute (`return $newsArticle->getHeadline();`) fails with the following error message:

> Attempted to call an undefined method named "getHeadline" of class "Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection".

The new NewsType Class (except):

```
class NewsType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $searchedLanguage = $options['languageId'];
        $builder
            ->add('relatedTo', EntityType::class, array(
                'class' => 'Bundle:News',
                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('a')
                        ->where('a.deleted = 0')
                        ->orderBy('a.validFrom', 'ASC');
                },
                'choice_label' => function($relatedTo, $searchedLanguage) {
                    $newsArticle = $relatedTo
                            ->getNewsArticle()
                            ->filter(
                                function(NewsArticle $newsArticle) use ($searchedLanguage) {
                                    return $newsArticle->getLanguageId() === $searchedLanguage;
                                }
                            )
                    ;
                    return $newsArticle->getHeadline();
                },
                'multiple' => true, 
                'expanded' => false,
                'required' => false
            ))
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Acme\Bundle\Entity\News',
            'languageId' => 'Acme\Bundle\Entity\Language',
        ));
    }
}
```

What can I do to get the `NewsArticle` entity instead of the ArrayCollection?

Thank´s in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The way you defined your mapping, `$newsArticles` in `News` is a OneToMany relation, meaning there are several `NewsArticles` for each `News`. So obviously, `getNewsArticles` returns a `Collection` of `NewsArticles`.

Either you defined your mapping wrong, and there should be only 1 NewsArticle by News, so replace your `OneToMany` by a `OneToOne`...
Either you should select on of the several `NewsArticle` to display its title.

**EDIT:** Following your indications in the comments, here's what you should do (assuming you have $searchedLanguage in a variable).

```
'choice_label' => function($news) {
    $article = $news->getNewsArticle()->filter(function (NewsArticle $article) use ($searchedLanguage) {
        return $this->getLanguageId() === $searchedLanguage;
    });

    return $article->getHeadline();
},
```

Comment: The OneToMany relation is correct. As described before, NewsArticle is just a container which contains the translations of the fields headline, subheader and bodytext; one News has Many NewsArticles.

Comment: The field 'relatedTo' should contain a list of the entity News. each News record should be labeled with the headline of the related entity NewsArticle having a specific language-id.

Comment: $searchedLanguage is in the NewsController available in a variable (how can I access this variable in the NewsType class?). For testing puposes I modified your code example and replaced $searchedLanguage with the ID of the default language. Unfortunately I get an error, because NewsArticle is no object, but an Array:

Error: Call to a member function getHeadline() on a non-object

Comment: For your 1st question, pass the languageId into the options of the Form (`$this->createForm(NewsType::class, $news, ['languageId' => $searchedlanguage])`) For your second, your NewsArticle IS an object (or at least supposed to be) since you have a class to represent it. But it looks like the `filter` method I wrote does not select any Article. I can't help you more on that, since it's your business code it's about.

Comment: Thanks for your explanations, seems like I´m quite close. But I´m still doing something wrong by passing the languageId. In my NewsController, the object of the default language is defined as `$lang`. I followed you example by configuring the form like this: `$form = $this->createForm(NewsType::class, $news, ['languageId' => $lang]);`
 Now I get an error for this line `$article = $news->getNewsArticle()->filter(function (NewsArticle $article) use ($lang)` : "Notice: Undefined variable: lang" ... any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Define `$lang = $options['languageId']` at the start of your `buildForm`